# How to detect swipe gesture in mvvmcross

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using `mvvmcross` pattern. I have a list of datasets. I am showing only one dataset on the view. When user swipes either left or right, then I need to reload the view to show corresponding dataset.

My dataset is big (around 100), I am afraid to use `viewpager`, it might be an issue in terms of memory.

I have used the following approach before [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures), but I wonder how to detect/implement `swipe gesture` in `mvvmcross` ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to re-invent the wheel here. For your scenario I believe using  a view pager with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is the better choice since it automatically destroys views that are not visible and recreate them when they are about to become visible again. Hence there is less memory consumption.

Comment: Thing is, you don't really implement swipe gesture for mvvmcross. If you need swipes, the best solution, is to implement a native way to do what you want, and when the swipe is correctly detected in your Platform-specific code, then you manually trigger a command in your viewmodel. What is handled by the MvvmCross Framework is "abstract" as it is only the intelligence of your app. Gestures are more of a UI feature, so to be implemented on each platform

Comment: Do you have an example of your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swipe gestures are a View concern and are generally not implemented in a MVVM framework. MvvmCross has a Tap gesture recognizer for iOS only.

So since it is a View concern you should look at how this is done natively on Android.